# Searching through document inside of document bad practice?

Tags: c#, mongodb, database

I have documents in my "events" collection that are built similar to this:

```
{
   eventname: "blah",
   invitees: [
     {
        inviteid: 1,
        userid: 34234
     },
     {
        inviteid: 2,
        userid: 5232
     }]
}
```

If I wanted all the events that user: "34234" was invited to, would it be in efficient to search through each `invitees` array in every event document?  seems like over kill.  I understand this would be great for relational databases, but can this be done well in mongodb?

UPDATE:

I ended up using this, and it worked, but still don't know if this is a great way of doing it:
`_Events.Collection.FindAll().Where(x => x.Invitees.Any(y => y.UserId == userId)).ToList();`

Answer (score 1):

On the contrary, such queries will fit nicely into MongoDB.
It allows you to apply a MultiKey index : an index for a field who's data type is array.

```
db.events.ensureIndex( { "invitees.userid" : 1 })
```

This way, you don't have to search each array within each document

Comment: Thank you for the response, I was wondering how i would then return my results in this case?  `ensureIndex` is a void method and I don't quite understand how this would apply in my situation to return a list of events

Comment: The 'ensureIndex()' only create index in order to list document, use: 'db.events.find({"invitees.userid" : 34234})' to retrieve only the inviteid use: 'db.events.find({"invitees.userid" : 34234}, {"invitees.inviteid" : 1})'

Comment: ok so after you create the index, how do you query against it?

Comment: for a list of documents use: `db.events.find({"invitees.userid" : 34234})`. To retrieve only the inviteid use: `db.events.find({"invitees.userid" : 34234}, {"invitees.inviteid" : 1})`

Comment: I tried this, it doesnt compile in visual studio, I am using the 10gen c# driver and im trying that to insert that object into the `.find` method and its just saying invalid expression,  It only accepts a MongoQuery Object

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about mongodb, but you can easily perform the search using Linq:

```
var results = 
    from evt in events
    where evt.invitees.Any(x => x.userid == 34234)
    select evt;
```

If the number of events is relatively small, this would be pretty fast.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's anything wrong with it, it's one of the benefits of a document database. If anything, you should have an index on it. See the [mongodb documentation on indexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/#indexes-on-embedded-fields).